# How to Connect AWS neptune database in Java Project IDE IntelliJ

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-neptune, intellij-13

we are planning to migrate data from AuroraDB to AWS neptune ( Property Graph) . I have all the data in AWS neptune.
I have to write API to interact with the AWS neptune. I need Connection details and Jars.
please provide details, we are using Gremlin language queries in API to fetch the information from AWS neptune.
Please provide steps and details to connect my Java project to AWS neptune.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting with a Gremlin Server (Neptune in this case) you can use the Apache TinkerPop Java client. It allows you to write Gremlin as part of your Java code. The client has classes that allow you to connect to the server via a WebSocket. You can either copy the Jar files from the Apache TinkerPop Gremlin Console download or pull them from Maven.

The TinkerPop documentation is [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/) and the Java client specific documentation is [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-drivers-variants)

The Neptune specific documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-java.html)

Comment: thanks Kelvin for your response. Error:Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.

Comment: error: Sep 01, 2021 8:36:49 PM io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer exceptionCaught
WARNING: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing:

Comment: So many things could be going on there. You may want to create a new question that includes some example code and describes how you are connecting to the server. If you do please include mention of where your code is running and how you are accessing the Neptune VPC etc.